# JS showing div using url

Tags: javascript

I have a code that shows a hidden div when a "?a='enter div number'"code was entered on the last part of the url.

```
<html>
<title> </title>
<head> 
</head>

<body>
<div id="tab1" style="display:none" > 
<p> "This is div 1" </p>
</div>

<div id="tab2" style="display:none"> 
<p> "This is div 2" </p>
    </div>

        <div id="tab3" style="display:none">
        <p> "This is div 3" </p>
        </div>
    </body> 
<script type="text/javascript">

if (window.location == 'http://localhost/assignment.html'){
document.getElementById("tab1").style.display="block";
}

if (window.location == 'http://localhost/assignment.html?a=2'){
document.getElementById("tab2").style.display="block";
}

if (window.location == 'http://localhost/assignment.html?a=3'){
document.getElementById("tab3").style.display="block";
}else{
document.getElementById("tab1").style.display="block";
}



</script>


</html>
```

somehow when I enter http://localhost/assignment.html?a=2 the result gives a "this is div1" and "this is div2"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last `else`statement only applies to your last `if` statement and so `tab1` is *always* shown when `a != 3`. I think you meant to use `else if`:

```
if (window.location == 'http://localhost/assignment.html') {
    document.getElementById("tab1").style.display = "block";
} else if (window.location == 'http://localhost/assignment.html?a=2') {
    document.getElementById("tab2").style.display = "block";
} else if (window.location == 'http://localhost/assignment.html?a=3') {
    document.getElementById("tab3").style.display = "block";
} else {
    document.getElementById("tab1").style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: follow up question. Can I store the window.location on a variable and make it static then use it for comparison inside elseif?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (window.location == 'http://localhost/assignment.html?a=3'){
   document.getElementById("tab3").style.display="block";
}else{ // Problem is in this else statment
   document.getElementById("tab1").style.display="block";
}
```

In this part of code you check if location is not `http://localhost/assignment.html?a=3` show '`tab1'` div. You can delete this part ( from `else` ).